# Can't create appropriate selector to grab names

Tags: css-selectors, web-scripting

How can I grab all the names under "Followed by" category from the below elements. The way the name have been laid out is kinda foreign to me that is why I can't get all of them. I have already used a selector which is capable of grabbing the first one. However, I expect to have all the names under "Followed by" title and until "edited_into" title. Thanks in advance.

Here is a link to the elements within which the required names are:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzmvfc75szlgyyn/elements%20for%20expression.txt?dl=0

The selector I've tried with:

```
a#followed_by+h4.li_group+div.odd a
```

The result I'm having is only the first name:

```
Star Trek V: The Final Frontier
```

Btw, my only intention is to parse the names using this selector not to style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector you have is almost correct.

```
a#followed_by+h4.li_group ~ div.soda a
```

The `~` works differently to the `+` in that it will select any matching element after the first part of the selector, whereas the `+` will only select elements immediately following the first part of the selector.
Of course, by "first part" I am referring to `a#followed_by+h4.li_group`.

I've also changed the selector to find `div.soda` rather than `div.odd` so you get all relevant elements, rather than just the odd ones.

---

Because of the way CSS selectors work, we can't ask for "only elements up until `edited_into`". We can, however resolve this using JavaScript.

A simple `for` loop with a conditional `break` will be the simplest method.

```
var titles = [];
var items = document.querySelectorAll('a#followed_by+h4.li_group ~ div.soda a');
//firstEditedIntoItem represents the first element in
//the `edited_into` section. If it's null, then there
//is none, and we have nothing to worry about.
var firstEditedIntoItem = 
    document.querySelector
    ('a#edited_into+h4.li_group+div.soda a, a#spin_off_from+h4.li_group+div.soda a');
    //   Note: This selector will find the first instance that matches any of the
    //   specified sections. You could add another and replace `spin_off_from` with
    //   another section id.
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    var it = items[i];
    //don't accept elements after 'edited_into'
    // If firstEditedIntoItem is null, it will not match either.
    if(it==firstEditedIntoItem) break;
    titles.push(it.textContent);
}
console.info(titles.join('\n'));
```

Comment: Thanks mike for your solution. Using your selector, I'm getting all the names after "followed by" title which is partially what i want. However, my intention is to start from followed by title but stops as soon as it finds "edited_into" title. Otherwise it will grab all of them. Perhaps you didn't notice that I also mentioned it in my description above. Thanks again mike.

Comment: Oh, of course - you're right I missed that part, somehow. It's not really possible to do this purely with CSS - unless I'm missing something. Assuming JS is fine, you can stop processing the list after you encounter the first element after the "edited_into" section. I can update the answer with some example code if you're interested.

Comment: Very much interested. Btw, I am accepting your answer. Hope you will edit the part you offered.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer with some example code. Removing the comments, it's just 8 lines of code; so should be fairly easy to follow - but let me know if you would like more explanation.